# Calculate Percentage using query in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

I want to calculate percentage of two columns after sum of the existing record related to specific user.

```html
SELECT SUM(total_marks) AS TotalMarks, 
SUM(obt_marks) AS ObtainedMarks, 
TotalMarks/ObtainedMarks*100 As Percentage 
FROM ExamResult WHERE (student_id = '5')
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot use column aliases once they are defined.  Instead, repeat the expressions:

```
SELECT SUM(total_marks) AS TotalMarks, 
       SUM(obt_marks) AS ObtainedMarks, 
       SUM(total_marks)  * 100.0 / SUM(obt_marks) As Percentage 
FROM ExamResult
WHERE student_id = 5;
```

Notes:

- I removed the single quotes around `5`.  Presumably, the id column is a number, not a string.  (If it is a string, keep the quotes).
- I multiplied by 100 *before* the division.  I find this logic easier to follow (you don't have to think about which is processed first, the multiplication or division).
- I added a decimal point to the `100`.  This prevents integer division, if the columns happen to be integers.

Comment: the query generate result greater than 100.. see the screen shot and tell me please http://prnt.sc/mynvev

Comment: SELECT        SUM(total_marks) AS TotalMarks, SUM(obt_marks) AS ObtainedMarks, SUM(obt_marks) * 100 / SUM(total_marks) AS Percentage
FROM            ExamResult
WHERE        (student_id = 5)

Comment: This query generate accurate result..Thanks for the help.